# How to configure PHPUnit with ZF version 1.12.11

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit

I am using zend framework 1.12.11 and now I want to use PHPunit with it.Pear has stopped it's stopped support for phpunit.Now it's working with composer.
I have install composer and phpunit via composer.But Where I have to put composer json setting file and my project and what should include in my project which automatically take phpunit of composer

Answer (score 0):

Per the [PHPUnit documentation for Composer installation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/installation.html#installation.composer), add PHPUnit to the dependencies in your project's `composer.json` file, something like:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "4.6.*"
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update -vvv phpunit/phpunit
```

to actually bring PHPUnit and its dependencies down into your project.

I usually add the -vvv (maximally verbose) flag to see what's going on under the hood. Feel free to omit if you prefer.

Once they are all installed, you can run `phpunit` the usual way by accessing the executable bin script that PHPUnit and Composer expose for you. From the project root, you should be able to run:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit --version
```

to confirm the install is ok.

Once you have a `phpunit.xml` config file set up that your test suites and directories, you should be able to run your tests using:

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit -c /path/to/phpunit.xml
```

Comment: I have installed zend server and XAMPP when run unit test It looks phpunit from xampp  also i have used composer and autoload it in my project  root.It also include phpunit while testing. what is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "run unit test"? Specifically, how are you invoking phpunit? Via command-line? From an IDE? From which directory? Bottom line: You need to invoke the desired phpunit - presumably the composer-installed one.

Comment: I am invoking phpunit via command line from myproject test folder